# Операторы сравнения в MySql

Tags: mysql

Есть база данных

```
 _________________________________________________________
     id       |   parent_id           |    title         |
  ____________|_______________________|__________________|
     1        |           0           |     каталог      |
 _____________|_______________________|__________________|
     2        |            1          |      меню 1      |
______________|_______________________|__________________|
     3        |            1          |      меню 2      |
______________|_______________________|__________________|
```

пытаюсь создать выборку для всех у кого значение parentId больше нуля. Набрал вот так:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE parent_id => 1
```

выдает такую ошибку:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=> 1' at line 1.

Не подскажите в чем проблема ?

Comment: вот так обычно это пишется >=

Comment: теперь такая ошибка пишется Unknown column 'parentId' in 'where clause'

Comment: @Dmitry  так я вроде так и написал

Comment: у вас в таблице написано одно, а в коде другое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас ошибка в синтаксисе сравнения. Правильная запись будет такая:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE parent_id >= 1
```

Comment: так вываливается ощибка #1054 - Unknown column 'parent_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: @Sergalas название колонки проверьте

Comment: там код был не живой сейчас поправил да и с >= вы были прав принимаю ответ